# C++ Palindrome Unique solution , giving error

Tags: c++, palindrome

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        if(x < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if(x < 10){
          return true;
        }
        int s = 0;
        int en = floor(log10(x));
        while(s < en){
          if(x % 10 != ((x / int(pow(10, en))))) {
              return false;
          }
          x = (x % int(pow(10, en))) / 10;
          s++;
          en--;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

this code is passing many of the test cases but fails at test cases like 9999,11211,112211 and returns false

code explanation
in this code, I am taking two variables s stands for start and en stands for end
through these two variables, I am running a while loop while iterating through the integer from left and right and checking if they are equal or not

[https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/]
I was doing it here

I was trying to print whether the number is palindrome or not in O(n/2) time

Comment: What did you see when you stepped through the code in a debugger for a known failing case?

Comment: You shouldn't use floating-point functions (like `pow` and `log10`) in a problem of integers.

Comment: Your code is mathematically correct (I think) but C++ is not mathematically correct so it fails in practice. Convert the number to a string of digits, then work on the string

Comment: this code has no error but is giving false on test cases

Comment: @AnujGarg Yes, for the reasons that have been explained. C++ function like `pow` and `log10` are not guaranteed to give accurate results. Your code only works if they do give accurate results.

Comment: @AnujGarg "this code has no error but is giving false on test cases" - Please read what you just wrote there and think about it...

Comment: As far as I can tell, that fails on most palindrome number of more than three digits, which should be long before any floating-point issues appear (but they will eventually).

Comment: For instance, with 9999 you end up with `if (99 % 10 != 99 / 100) { return false; }`. The few cases that work include zeros.

Comment: Whi you don't do std::to_string and then compare the characters?

Answer (score 0):

#### It's really in your interest to convert to a decimal string first!

That avoids a whole world of woe.
Once you do that, it is extremely simple.

Where did you get the idea of aiming for O(n/2)? Only the power of n matters in such expressions. Did you mean n^(1/2)?

And avoid saying things like `this code has no error but is giving false on test cases`, because it makes readers laugh.

Comment: in O(n/2) time complexity , i know i can do this easily using maps but i was just trying other method and build this logic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what requirements exist, and what exactly you are trying to do and why.

I believe if I were ever faced with this specific problem I would convert the (base10) number into an array of characters and then do the comparisons as char left vs char right.

To my knowledge there exist no good, reliable and performant way for taking a base10 value and convert it into a base2 or base16 and hence why converting it into a char seems like the most straightforward way. If it were in base2 or base16 you could just use bitshift and bitmasks to do the comparison, but since there is no good way to 'isolate and shift away' a base10 number it doesn't feel like a good approach to the problem and why you should instead convert each base10 number into a char.

See this for how to convert to char array: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars

Here is how that could look:

```
bool isPalindrome(int input)
{
    std::array<char, 32> arr;
    auto begin = arr.data();
    auto result = std::to_chars(begin, begin + sizeof(arr), input);
    auto end = result.ptr;
    auto numIterations = (end - begin) / 2;

    // todo: insert algorithm here 
    // foreach ...
    // char left = arr[...]
    // char right = arr[...]
    // compare left vs right
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You showed the original question in Leetcode in your link:

[Please see here.](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/). It allows in the first step to present a solution by converting the number into a string. That will result in a very simple piece of code, because you simply can construct a second and reversed string, using the `std::string`s range constructor with reverse iterators. So really simple.

Then Leetcode asks to do this also without string conversion. Here we can use the standard approach be splitting a number into digits with modulo and integer divisions. The digits that we extract will be multiplied with power of tens and with that reversed,

Please see the following simple example, showing both methods.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome1(int x) {
        std::string s{ std::to_string(x) };
        return (x >= 0) and (s == std::string{ s.rbegin(), s.rend() });
    }
    bool isPalindrome2(int x) {
        if (x < 0) return false;
        long long reversedNumber{}, y{ x }; // because of potential overflow
        while (y > 0) {
            reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + y % 10;
            y /= 10;
        }
        return x == reversedNumber;
    }
};
int main() {
    Solution s{};
    std::cout << s.isPalindrome1(123454321) << '\n';
    std::cout << s.isPalindrome2(123454321) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier that way?

```
bool isPalindrome(int x){
    auto str = std::to_string(x);
    int l = 0;
    int r = str.size()-1;
    while(l < r){
       if(str[l] != str[r]) return false;
       l++;
       r--;
    }
    return true;
}
```